# Помогите решить задачу на js ,буду очень благодарен

Tags: javascript

Вы с Васей и Петром решили выбрать самые лучшие фотографии котиков в интернете. Для этого каждую фотографию каждый из вас оценил по стобалльной шкале. Естественно, тут же встал вопрос о том, как из трех оценок получить одну финальную. Вы опасаетесь, что каждый из вас сильно завысит оценку фотографиям своего котика. Поэтому было решено в качестве финальной оценки брать не среднее арифметическое, а медиану, то есть просто отвергнуть максимальную и минимальную оценку. Вася начал писать код выбора средней оценки из трех, но запутался в if-ах, и потому передоверил эту задачу вам. Попытайтесь не просто решить задачу, но и минимизировать количество проверок и максимально упростить условия проверок.

Comment: **Помочь !== решить за вас**! Покажите ваши попытки и опишите, что не получилось.

Comment: Особо попыток не было,просто не понимаю как мне написать код к этой задаче

Comment: Ну конечно есть вопросы к автору этого задания, т.к. не очень понятно, как Вася и Петя(двое) поставили ТРИ оценки... Но тем не менее. Создайте переменную, положите в нее 3 значения(можно воспользоваться prompt если в браузере запускаете) и выбирайте среднее.

Comment: @SwaD, это как "А и Б, сидели на трубе. А упала, Б пропала. Кто остался на трубе? Так и тут - очевидно `Вы с Васей и Петром` это таки три человека. Для тебя это будет как `SwaD с Васей и Петром`. :)

Comment: @ksa ёксель... я "Вы" почему то выкинул из вопроса и считал себя третим лицом в этой задаче ))) Как порой бывает, мы тут что то решали, не решили, вот тебе, реши ) Теперь сложилось!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> Вася начал писать код выбора средней оценки из трех, но запутался в if-ах, и потому передоверил эту задачу вам. Попытайтесь не просто решить задачу, но и минимизировать количество проверок и максимально упростить условия проверок.

Мне кажется тут и проверки не нужны...

```js
const a = 9
const b = 20
const c = 30
console.log('Оценка', [c, a, b].sort((a, b) => a - b)[1])
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, теперь числа